# Is it possible to drag a flex component over the html page?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to know whether is it possible to drag a flex component, say the component is a draggable image, over an iframe that present in the application.

I have observed that whenever i do that the image is going behind the iframe and not over the iframe.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  When using an iFrame "integrated" with a Flex Application the whole purpose is usually to have the iFrame display above the Flash app so it looks integrated.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: Ok..I am thinking of something like inserting a screencap of that particular iframe in the parent whenever i want to drag over the iframe will that be ok?

Comment: Theoretically that should work if you can get a screencap of the iFrame content "on the fly"